# Animate SVG straight line by CSS transition

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, css-transitions, svg-animate

I want to move the line and the circle in the same way, and animate the transition with CSS.
It's working for the circle, not for the line.

What's wrong ?

```js
const state = {
  x: 75,
  y: 75
};
const line = document.getElementsByTagName('line')[0];
const circle = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[0];

setInterval(() => {
  state.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  state.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  line.setAttribute("x2", state.x);
  line.setAttribute("y2", state.y);
  circle.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${state.x} ${state.y})`);
}, 2000)
```

```css
circle,
line {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg height="150" width="150" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <line 
    x1="0"
    y1="0"
    x2="75"
    y2="75"
    stroke="red"
  >
  </line>
  <circle 
    r="10"
    transform="translate(75 75)"
    fill="none"
    stroke="blue"
  >
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to animate a circle and a line synchronously is to use the circle as a [marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker).

In this case, the circle will always be attached to the line and will animate along with it.

```js
const state = {
  x: 75,
  y: 75
};
const line = document.getElementsByTagName('line')[0];
const circle = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[0];

setInterval(() => {
  state.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  state.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  line.setAttribute("x2", state.x);
  line.setAttribute("y2", state.y);
 
}, 2000)
```

```html
<svg height="160" width="160" style="border: 1px solid black"> 
<defs>
  <marker id="markEnd"  viewBox="0 0 22 22" refX="10" refY="10"  markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="22" markerHeight="22">
  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="none"  stroke="blue" />
  </marker> 
</defs>
  <line 
    x1="0"
    y1="0"
    x2="75"
    y2="75"
    stroke="red" 
    marker-end="url(#markEnd)"
  >
  </line>
  
</svg>
```

**Update**

Option @AOD to replace the line with path and with a marker

```js
const state = {
  x: 75,
  y: 75
};
const line = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0];

setInterval(() => {
  state.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  state.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  line.setAttribute("d", `M 0 0 L ${state.x} ${state.y}`);
}, 2000)
```

```css
path {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg height="160" width="160" style="border: 1px solid black"> 
<defs>
  <marker id="markEnd"  viewBox="0 0 22 22" refX="10" refY="10"  markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="22" markerHeight="22">
  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="none"  stroke="blue" />
  </marker> 
</defs>
    <path
    class="line"
    d="M 0 0 L 75 75"
    stroke="red"
    fill="none"
    marker-end="url(#markEnd)"
    />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a Line element, you can use the Path element as follows:

```js
const state = {
  x: 75,
  y: 75
};
const line = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0];

setInterval(() => {
  state.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  state.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
  line.setAttribute("d", `M 0 0 l ${state.x} ${state.y}`);
}, 2000)
```

```css
path {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg height="150" width="150" style="border: 1px solid black">
    <path
    class="line"
    d="M 0 0 L 75 75"
    stroke="red"
    fill="none"
    />
</svg>
```